# VBA problem with type mismatch with add data

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to add another date next to the next one in the macro, i.e. if I have on G32 2021.01, I would like to add on H322021.02. However, my feature shows me the Type Mismatch here : `*.Range("H32").Value = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(DateAdd("m", 1, .Range("G32").Value), 0), "yyyy-mm")`
*

```
With wbMe.Sheets("strona 5")
.Range("F32:H42").UnMerge
.Range("G32:G42").Copy
.Range("F32").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
.Range("H32:H42").Copy
.Range("G32:G32").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
.Range("H32:H42").ClearContents
.Range("H32").Value = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(DateAdd("m", 1, .Range("G32").Value), 0), "yyyy-mm")
.Range("F32:H42").Merge
End With
```

Comment: If that line is erroring, it's likely that Excel is not recognising the contents of `G32` as a date, but as a string.

Comment: but i changed it manually to date before running the macro and it's the same

Answer (score 0):

Solution put instead

`.Range("H32").Value = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(DateAdd("m", 1, .Range("G32").Value), 0), "yyyy-mm")` to

`.Range("H32").Value = Format(DateAdd("m",1, Replace(.Range("G32"),".","-")), "yyyy-mm")`